# Spring MVC Sending Apache POI file to client browser from controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I'm attempting to pass an excel file that I have created with Apache POI to the client browser, which triggers a download on the browser.  I'm aware this is a common issue, but I cannot seem to figure out quite what I am doing wrong in this scenario.  It must be something small or logically incorrect.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin/home")
@Api(tags = {"site_endpoint"})
@ResponseBody
public class FileDownloadController {

    private HttpServletResponse servletResponse;

    @Autowired
    public FileDownloadController(final HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
        this.servletResponse = servletResponse;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "download/downloadPage/{param1}/pageNum/{param2}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String, String> getByAsmsAndCountryCode(
            @PathVariable final String param1,
            @PathVariable final String param2,
            HttpServletResponse response){

        // Initialize worksheet here..
        final Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        //Add sheets to worksheet here ..//

        servletResponse.setContentType("application/x-ms-excel"); // Set up mime type
        servletResponse.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        try (
                OutputStream out = servletResponse.getOutputStream()) {
                workbook.write(out);
                servletResponse.getWriter();
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                this.response.put(FEEDBACK, "File is Downloaded.");
                LOGGER.info("Successful download " + fileName);
        } 
        catch (final IOException e) {
            this.response.put(FEEDBACK, "An IO error occurred");
            LOGGER.info("IO error occurred", e);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.response.put(FEEDBACK, e.toString());
            LOGGER.info("Other error");
        }
        return this.response;
    }
```

In the current state, a download of the file is not triggered on the browser.  Am I correctley using the OutputStream and Servlet Response to trigger this?

All help appreciated!

Comment: have you tried response.setContentType("application/force-download")?

Comment: @Kid101 Gave it a shot, still having the issue.

Comment: how are you trying to use this API in JS?? If you are directly calling your API via postman or browser are you able to download?